# Java 1.4 SHA265 Issue?

Tags: java, security, sha256, java1.4

I'm currently supporting a legacy e-commerce application that runs on Java 1.4.

I understand that 1.4 does not support SSL certificates signed with SHA256, is this correct and will I have issues establishing connections with other sites requesting the use of this certificate?

Are there any known workarounds to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not quite right: SHA-256 (and SHA-384, SHA-512) were introduced in 1.4.2

If there is no option to update you could use bouncycastle as your security provider. At http://www.bouncycastle.org/specifications.html#install (Section 5.0 Bouncy Castle Provider) you find information about registering it as a provider.