# Java deprecation of SHA-1 signatures: correct way to sign with SHA-256?

Tags: java, sha256, sign

In light of [Java's deprecation of SHA-1 signed code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41878258/java-9-deprecating-sha1-certificates-or-another-issue-at-work), I am transitioning to SHA-256. However, I am not sure whether, in order to comply with the new requirements, I should explicitly request the `-digestalg SHA-256` (if not, it sefaults to SHA-1, as per [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jarsigner.html)). (Side-note: although the public-private key pair in my JKS are `RSA`, I found I also had to explicitly ask `-sigalg SHA256withRSA`.)

Java 9 "early access" seems to accept just fine the `SHA1` digest algorithm, as long as the signature algorithm is `SHA256withRSA`. I searched for a clear explanation of these exact terms (in the context...as reported by a `jarsigner` verification: "Digest algorithm", "Signature algorithm") / their implications, without too much success, though.

The JREs I am targeting are 6 or better. Using Java 6 on the build machine as well.

[L.E.] More confusingly for me, it seems that the jarsigner (in Java 9) verifies the jars (read: no complaints raised) even when both the digest algorithm and the signature algorithm are `SHA-1`, just on account that I have used an `SHA256` certificate.

[L.E. 2] Interestingly, signing on Java 9 w/o providing any of the custom flags, and using the same JKS, everything is signed as expected:

`Digest algorithm: SHA-256
 Signature algorithm: SHA256withRSA, 2048-bit key`

I very much think this behavior underlines the "proper practice", rather than Java 6's. This may very well become the answer to this question...once Java 9 will be release.

As another side-note, the [Java Crypto Roadmap](https://www.java.com/en/jre-jdk-cryptoroadmap.html) announces the same plan (`Disable SHA-1 in certificate chains anchored by roots included by default in Oracle's JDK; local or enterprise CAs are not affected. Signed code that is timestamped before 2017-01-01 is not affected.`) for Java 6, 7, 8 as well.