# Since which java version SHA-256 and SHA256withRSA are supported for timestamp at signed jar files

Tags: java, security, sha256

I have the following entry in the signature of my jar file

```
Timestamped by "CN=GlobalSign TSA for Advanced - G3 - 001-02, O=GMO GlobalSign K.K., C=JP" on Mo Apr 10 11:48:34 UTC 2017
 Timestamp digest algorithm: SHA-256
 Timestamp signature algorithm: SHA256withRSA, 2048-bit key
```

I already found out that the SHA-256 at the timestamp digest algoirthm and the SHA256withRSA at the timestamp signature algorithm are causing problems when running the jar file on a system which java version is below 1.7.0_76 (jar file is treaded as unsigned).

Can somebody tell me from which java versions on these two algorithms are supported at the timestamp digest and at the timestamp signature?

Comment: Be so kind and leave a comment when you downvote. Thank you!

Comment: I don't understand why this was down-voted. This is a very important question with no answers on oracle websites. The new JRE requires SHA-256 signature, however SHA-256 is not recognized in old Java versions. How we can handle this situation?

Comment: Thank you for the hint about java 1.9. As you say SHA-1 will be disabled soon (https://www.java.com/en/jre-jdk-cryptoroadmap.html).

Answer (score 2):

Java version below 1.7.0_76 not supporting SHA-256 for timestamping caused by https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8049480
(The fix included in 1.7.0_76 http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/2col/7u76-bugfixes-2389098.html)

From "Oracle JRE and JDK Cryptographic Roadmap", SHA-1 still not be planned to disable on code signing.

So I think the best choice (to support old Java version) for now is using SHA-1 as Timestamping algorithm. (Use below 8u101, 7u111 for signing **OR** Use the -tsadigestalg option on 8u101, 7u111 or above)

I have tested jar file signed with

```
Digest algorithm: SHA-256
Signature algorithm: SHA256withRSA, 2048-bit key
Timestamp digest algorithm: SHA-1
Timestamp signature algorithm: SHA1withRSA, 2048-bit key
```

work fine with Java 7, 8, 9(ea+174)

Comment: I basically agree with your answer, thank you. Nevertheless I am concerned of when SHA-1 will be finally deprecated by java. As you write in your answer and as it is described within [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41878258/java-9-deprecating-sha1-certificates-or-another-issue-at-work), SHA-1 will not be deprecated for now. Nevertheless our software is rolled out to many customers and we want to avoid unnecessary updates.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to just not time-stamp the jar file.
Waiting for some better recommendation...