# JDK Jarsigner : jar is unsigned. (signatures missing or not parsable)

Tags: java, unsigned, verify, jarsigner

I Signed with JDK:1.8 jarsigner.
Verify Results with JDK:1.8:

```
C:\glassfish4\jdk8\bin\jarsigner -verify sample_sha1_sha1.jar -verbose

  Timestamped by "***" on Wed Jun 06 17:59:57 UTC 2018
    Timestamp digest algorithm: SHA-1
    Timestamp signature algorithm: SHA256withRSA, 2048-bit key

jar verified.
```

But same signed jar when i verify with JDK: 1.7_21_b11, it says jar unsigned.
Results:

```
C:\glassfish4\jdk7\bin\jarsigner -verify sample_sha1_sha1.jar -verbose

         898 Wed Jun 06 17:59:56 IST 2018 META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
 m       172 Wed Nov 16 18:45:40 IST 2016 META-INF/NOTICE
 m     10351 Wed Nov 16 18:45:40 IST 2016 META-INF/LICENSE

  s = signature was verified
  m = entry is listed in manifest
  k = at least one certificate was found in keystore
  i = at least one certificate was found in identity scope

jar is unsigned. (signatures missing or not parsable)
```

Please help me how to solve this.

Comment: What if you sign with JDK 7?

Comment: That works very well, but as part of migration I have to sign with the Java 8 version with timestamp and that's not getting verified in client environment which is Java 7. So is there any way or does Java 7 not support timestamp thing?

Comment: Just a guess: JDK 7u21 may be too old. Can you check with newer JDK 7 (e.g. JDK 7u80)?

Comment: yah it works with JDK7u80. But need to know why its not working in 1.7_21. I know this is somethings which needs to upgrade in client side too, but wanted to know if there is a way or some version bug?

Comment: I think some algorithms were not supported in versions before 7u80. See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43631322/since-which-java-version-sha-256-and-sha256withrsa-are-supported-for-timestamp-a